# Check if a site is blocked in India

Tags: dns

I need to test if a given domain is resolving in India.

I know the Indian government blocks some domains they don't like, by forcing network operators to not resolve them. This is for example a picture I found on the web: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWyfs.jpg. In this case it's a video streaming site, but it also happens with all the legal adult sites, see for example this [news](https://www.indiatoday.in/technology/news/story/govt-says-porn-sites-blocked-by-jio-airtel-and-others-after-3-court-orders-hints-watching-porn-not-illegal-1573466-2019-07-25).

So I'm trying to find a way to tell if a domain is blocked, by doing a `nslookup domain server`

But I couldn't find any available dns server that answers to me. I found some public dns lists, but they don't honor the government block. I think I need the servers used by the mobile carriers, can someone provide me one or a page that contains this information? Or, if it exists, another way to tell if a domain is blocked?

Answer (score 1):

When domains are blocked, they are not blocked by blocking DNS requests. They are blocked by blocking ip ranges.

One could simply bypass a DNS request by setting google as DNS servers for example, but with a geographical ban, IP ranges are blocked.

That is also the reason why usually a VPN can bypass such ban.

Comment: Are you sure? From the screenshots they sent me, the Chrome error was about the domain not resolved. Also I don't think it's the IP, because we have many sites on the same IP, and some of them are working, while others not

Comment: Normally a goverment will order a blacklist of ip adresses if a country must be blocked. DNS is too easy to circumvent.

Comment: @LPChip lot of ISPs in India hijack DNS requests. see: https://shantanugoel.com/2016/09/17/indian-isp-act-fibernet-blocks-bit-ly-does-dns-hijacking/

Comment: No, In India most ISPs use DNS Blocking, and they will also block DNS over TLS/HTTPS. Only working way to bypass this is to use DnsCrypt.

Answer (score -1):

Google for "public India dns servers" and test with the server IPs returned like this:

`host your-domain dns-server-ip`

Comment: yes, that's why I'm searching for the `dns-server-ip`, the ones I found online are resolving the blacklisted sites